# Sudden Wifi Adapter not found error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, adapter

I checked a lot of other posts here but sadly none of them worked for me. I'm posting a few commonly asked outputs from the terminal:
**(1) sudo lshw -c network**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: 34:64:a9:ca:d6:1f
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:35 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0b00000-f0b00fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff   
*-network:0
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 2
           logical name: ham0
           serial: 7a:79:19:11:52:a2
           size: 10Mbit/s
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full ip=25.17.82.162 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s   
*-network:1
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 3
           logical name: enp0s16u1
           serial: 2a:92:a1:c1:78:cc
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.128 link=yes multicast=yes
```

**(2) lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1566
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R2 Graphics]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 156b
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1537
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (rev 01)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1580
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1581
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1582
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1583
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1584
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1585
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

**(3) lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3121 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2717:ff80  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**(4) iwconfig**

```
ham0      no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s16u1  no wireless extensions.
```

**(5) rfkill list**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**(6) Secure boot disabled**

Any help is appreciated.
I'm running an old HP 245 laptop with AMD processor and (probably) MediaTek Wifi card, which seemed to mess up.

Comment: The WiFi card isn't being detected. 2 possible causes: (1) disabled in BIOS/UEFI or (2) disconnected or defective.

Comment: On my friends' suggestion, I tried upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. Weirdly, the wifi worked today morning, and then after upgrading, I faced the same error. How can I check for (1) and (2)?